# Why is there a problem with building the project?

Tags: gulp

Everything used to work fine, even in this project there were no problems at the beginning, now it doesn’t knock any errors, but when you enter the **gulp** or **gulp build** command, the assembly stops if you try several times, then the assembly completes successfully, also if the **gulp** command works make changes to **css** and **js** then everything works well, but if you make some changes to **html**, then this is not reflected in the browser and you need to restart everything.

```js
[13:51:33] Using gulpfile D:\Work\Taker Corporation\Automation\gulpfile.js
[13:51:33] Starting 'default'...
[13:51:33] Starting 'clean'...
[13:51:33] Finished 'clean' after 6.71 ms
[13:51:33] Starting 'build'...
[13:51:33] Starting 'clean'...
[13:51:33] Finished 'clean' after 272 μs
[13:51:33] Starting 'html:build'...
```

```js
[Browsersync] Serving files from: dist/
[13:51:56] Starting 'html:build'...
[Browsersync] Reloading Browsers... (buffered 9 events)
```

```js
"use strict";

var gulp = require("gulp"),
    autoprefixer = require("gulp-autoprefixer"),
    cssbeautify = require("gulp-cssbeautify"),
    removeComments = require('gulp-strip-css-comments'),
    rename = require("gulp-rename"),
    sass = require("gulp-sass"),
    rigger = require("gulp-rigger"),
    uglify = require("gulp-uglify"),
    watch = require("gulp-watch"),
    plumber = require("gulp-plumber"),
    run = require("run-sequence"),
    rimraf = require("rimraf"),
    webserver = require("browser-sync");



/* Paths to source/build/watch files
=========================*/

var path = {
    build: {
        html: "dist/",
        js: "dist/assets/js/",
        css: "dist/assets/css/",
        img: "dist/assets/img/",
        fonts: "dist/assets/fonts/",
        json: "dist/assets/"
    },
    src: {
        html: "src/*.{htm,html,php}",
        js: "src/assets/js/*.js",
        css: "src/assets/sass/*.scss",
        img: "src/assets/img/**/*.*",
        fonts: "src/assets/fonts/**/*.*",
        json: "src/assets/*.json"
    },
    watch: {
        html: "src/**/*.{htm,html,php}",
        js: "src/**/*.js",
        css: "src/**/*.scss",
        img: "src/assets/img/**/*.*",
        fonts: "src/assets/fonts/**/*.*",
        json: "src/assets/*.json"
    },
    clean: "./dist"
};



/* Webserver config
=========================*/

var config = {
    server: "dist/",
    notify: false,
    open: true,
    ui: false
};



/* Tasks
=========================*/

gulp.task("webserver", function () {
    webserver(config);
});


gulp.task("html:build", function () {
    return gulp.src(path.src.html)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(rigger())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
    .pipe(webserver.reload({stream: true}));
});


gulp.task("css:build", function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.css)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
        browsers: ["last 8 versions"],
        cascade: true
    }))
    .pipe(cssbeautify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(webserver.reload({stream: true}));
});


gulp.task("js:build", function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.js)
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(rigger())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename("main.min.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.js))
    .pipe(webserver.reload({stream: true}));
});


gulp.task("fonts:build", function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.fonts)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.fonts));
});


gulp.task("image:build", function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.img)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.img));
});


gulp.task("json:build", function() {
    gulp.src(path.src.json)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.json));
});


gulp.task("clean", function (cb) {
    rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});


gulp.task('build', function (cb) {
    run(
        "clean",
        "html:build",
        "css:build",
        "js:build",
        "fonts:build",
        "image:build",
        "json:build"
        , cb);
});


gulp.task("watch", function() {
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start("html:build");
    });
    watch([path.watch.css], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start("css:build");
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start("js:build");
    });
    watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start("image:build");
    });
    watch([path.watch.fonts], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start("fonts:build");
    });
    watch([path.watch.json], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start("json:build");
    });
});


gulp.task("default", function (cb) {
   run(
       "clean",
       "build",
       "webserver",
       "watch"
   , cb);
});
```

Comment: You are using a lot of gulp v3-style code, like `gulp.start` (which was never really supposed to be used by end users) and `run-sequence` and `gulp-watch`.  I would suggest updating the code - it would be pretty easy, there isn't much to do.

Comment: @Mark You're right, I'm really using **gulp v3.9.1** so far everything worked, so I didn't update anything. Do you have some examples of good builds on **gulp v4** for simple sites?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `gulp-watch`, it watches for changes : https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch

Comment: Added gulpfile.js